# Altering the Littlest Jupyterhub login page on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, jupyterhub

I can't seem to find the JupyterHub html files to edit on Google Cloud.
I created a new VM to host TLJH and want to chagne the html of the login page but don't know how to access those files through Google Cloud and it doesn't look like you can through the Jupyter interface.

Where do I find the html files?

Comment: Which GCP product are you using?

Comment: @R.Esteves a VM Instance under Compute - with Ubuntu 18.04 set up as in TLJH docs [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/google.html).